# System.NotSupportedException when calling OData service from NetCoreApp2.1

Tags: .net-core, odata

I have set up a multi targetting (net4.5.2/netstandard2) class library allowing to consume one of our enterprise OData services.
To access this OData service we use a proxy class generated with the [OData v4 Client Code Generator (v7.5.0)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator)

Unfortunately, when trying to use my library in a Netcoreapp2.1 application I encounter an issue as soon as I try to enumerate a collection.

`Container.MyDataSet.ToList();` produces the following exception :

> "System.NotSupportedException : This target framework does not enable
>   you to directly enumerate over a data service query. This is because
>   enumeration automatically sends a synchronous request to the data
>   service. Because this framework only supports asynchronous operations,
>   you must instead call the BeginExecute and EndExecute methods to
>   obtain a query result that supports enumeration."

I do not encounter this issue when using this same multitarget library in a .Net 4.5.2 application.

Having a look at the Microsoft.OData.Client v7.5.0 source code, this behaviour seems to be by design with specific handling of the .Net Core case.

Did I miss something ?

The following code prevents the issue, but it is barely usable :

```
var query = (DataServiceQuery<MyData>)Container.MyDataSet;
var taskFactory = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<MyData>>();
var t = taskFactory.FromAsync(query.BeginExecute(null, null), data => query.EndExecute(data));
t.ConfigureAwait(false);
IEnumerable<MyData> result = t.Result;
```

How can I use an OData IQueryable in .Net Core application without adding specific code ?

Comment: The error explains what's wrong. You tried to convert the *query* to a list, not the results. An OData query is *not* an EF query that gets executed when you call `ToList()`.

Comment: It seems the *actual* question is how to make ODATA calls asynchronously in .NET Core, not how to use `ToList()` and the answer isn't straightforward. Saying "it's a mess" would be more appropriate. I can see a `GetAllPagesAsync` that actually delegates to `TaskFactory.FromAsync` in the source. `git blame` shows this is 4-year old code, written this way to target .NET 4.0. It's safe to assume it doesn't use HttpClient either. You could try a different generator or convert the query to a URL and call it asynchronously with `HttpClient.GetAsync`. `DataServiceQuery.ToString()` will return the URI

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used `ToList()` to illustrate the problem with a simple example. You are righ ; it uses and underlying HttpWebRequest. I will give more precision to my question and see what I can achieve with the Uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by @PanagiotisKanavos `DataServiceQuery.ToString()` will return the uri of the OData query.
Based on this, I wrote my own `IQueryable` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

using Microsoft.OData.Client;

public class ODataLinqQuery<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    public IQueryProvider Provider { get; }

    private DataServiceQuery<T> DataServiceQuery { get; }

    public ODataLinqQuery(DataServiceQuery<T> dataServiceQuery, MyClient client, Type finalType)
    {
        this.DataServiceQuery = dataServiceQuery;
        this.Provider = new ODataLinqQueryProvider<T>(dataServiceQuery, client, finalType);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Provider.Execute<IEnumerable<T>>(this.Expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.Provider.Execute<System.Collections.IEnumerable>(this.Expression).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Expression Expression => this.DataServiceQuery.Expression;

    public Type ElementType => typeof(T);
}
```

Where MyClient is an utility class which wraps an HttpClient, handles authentication token, and performs result deserialization.
FinalType is to keep track on the type I want to obtain and deserialize, as I am handling `IQueryables` over interfaces.
Then I wrote my own `IQueryProvider` :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net.Http;

using Microsoft.OData.Client;

public class ODataLinqQueryProvider<T> : IQueryProvider
{
    private MyClient Client { get; set; }

    private DataServiceQuery<T> DataServiceQuery { get; set; }

    private Type FinalType { get; }

    public ODataLinqQueryProvider(
        DataServiceQuery<T> dsq,
        MyClient client,
        Type finalType)
    {
        this.DataServiceQuery = dsq;
        this.Client = client;
        this.FinalType = finalType;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new ODataLinqQuery<T>(this.DataServiceQuery, this.Client, this.FinalType);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        var pro = new DataServiceQuery<TElement>(expression, this.DataServiceQuery.Provider as DataServiceQueryProvider);
        return new ODataLinqQuery<TElement>(pro, this.Client, this.FinalType);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        this.DataServiceQuery = new DataServiceQuery<T>(expression, this.DataServiceQuery.Provider as DataServiceQueryProvider);
        return this.Execute();
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        this.DataServiceQuery = new DataServiceQuery<T>(expression, this.DataServiceQuery.Provider as DataServiceQueryProvider);
        var res = this.Execute();
        if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TResult)))
        {
            return (TResult)res;
        }
        else
        {
            return ((IEnumerable)res).Cast<TResult>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }

    private object Execute()
    {
        var result = Client.GetResult(typeof(OData<>).MakeGenericType(this.FinalType), HttpMethod.Get, new Uri(this.DataServiceQuery.ToString())) as OData;
        return result.Objects;
    }
}
```

Where `Odata<>` class is just for deserialization of the OData result and `GetResult` "just" invokes  the `GetAsync` method of its underlying `HttpClient` with the correct authentication headers, wait for and deserializes the result :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class OData<T> : OData where T : class
{
    public override IEnumerable<object> Objects => this.Value;

    public List<T> Value { get; set; }
}

public class OData
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
    public string Metadata { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<object> Objects { get; set; }
}
```

Finally I expose my `IQueryable` as follows :

```
var myQueryable = new ODataLinqQuery<MyData>(this.Container.MyDataSet, myclient, typeof(MyData));
```

I can then apply filters, orderby, top and skip and get the results as with a standard `IQueryable`. I know that this implementation is not complete, and `IQueryable` to OData is not as complete as most `IQueryable` to SQL, but it achieves the minimum I need.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the error message, the platform only supports asynchronous fetches. Even after you use that, you will likely need to enumerate over the results multiple times -- everytime you perform a `ToList()`, `FirstOrDefault()` or other similar `System.Generics.Collections` operations, you are essentially getting the `Enumerator` of the collection and enumerating over it.

I adopted this solution: immediately after I fetch enumerable results from the OData libraries I enumerate over them and put them in another enumerable container (`Dictionary<string, MyAwesomeResult>` in this case) instantiated by me.

```
var resultsQuery = this.oDataClient.MyAwesomeResults
    .AddQueryOption("$filter", "Name eq 'MyAwesomeName'")
    .AddQueryOption("$top", "5")
    .AddQueryOption("$skip", "2");

IEnumerable<MyAwesomeResult> resultsRaw = await 
resultsQuery.ExecuteAsync();
var results = new Dictionary<string, MyAwesomeResult>();`

foreach (var resultRaw in resultsRaw)
{
    results.Add(resultRaw.Key, resultRaw);
}
```

Then I use the container I instantiated -- I no longer need to enumerate again over the enumerable returned by 
`DataServiceQuery<MyAwesomeResult>.ExecuteAsync`.

Comment: Thanks. I know I can enumerate the result, but what if the undelying datasource is thousand or million lines ? The point is I can't present it as a "standard" `IQueryable` on which I can transparently apply filter, ordering, top and skip.

Comment: You can apply filters before you send out the OData request using `ExecuteAsync()`. I have updated the answer to illustrate this part.